# C - copy characters ASCII value to 64bits integer

Tags: c, ascii

As we all know, each printable character has its ascii value. I'm trying to 8 characters' ascii value to 64 bits integer, but it only copies 32 bits.

```
char * ch = "AAAABBBB";
unsigned long int i;

//copy charater's ascii to 64 bits int
memcpy(&i, ch, 8);
printf("integer hold: 0x%x\n", i);
```

Is there something wrong with this code?

Output I expect was:

```
integer hold: 0x4141414142424242
```

but output was:

```
integer hold: 0x41414141
```

Comment: Turn up your warnings!

Comment: @CarlNorum And what exactly would that solve? As far as a compiler is concerned, this code is just fine.

Comment: @Lundin, mismatched printf format strings cause undefined behaviour.  GCC and clang would both detect and warn about this problem.  Clang even gives a suggested solution!

Comment: @CarlNorum Where is the mismatched format string? GCC -Wall gives nothing, nor can I see anything wrong with this code, except the poor choice of declaring a pointer to a string literal as non-const. Printing an unsigned long variable with %x isn't undefined behavior, even if long is larger than int. As far as I know, taking a part of an unsigned long, for any reason, is always well-defined and will not lead to any trap representation.

Comment: `%x` is for an `unsigned int`, not an `unsigned long int`.  Mismatches are *always* undefined, even if any or all implementations happen to do something reasonable.  I'll go get the warnings output and paste it here the next time I'm at a computer.

Comment: @Lundin, from clang for a simple test program: "example.c:6:20: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has type 'unsigned long' [-Wformat]"  And from GCC: "example.c:6: warning: format ‘%x’ expects type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’".  In addition to the warning, clang provides the suggestion to replace `%x` with `%lx`.

Comment: @Lundin, I should note that I didn't even have to turn on any `-W` flags.  These messages were output by default with GCC 4.2.1 (old, I know, but I was on a Mac) and clang 3.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `unsigned long` is indeed a 64-bit type (you can output `sizeof(unsigned long)` to check this), you *still* need to use `%lx` format string to print it.

If `unsigned long` is 32 bits, you'll probably have to resort to `unsigned long long` and use the `%llx` format string.

From `C11 7.20.6.1 The fprintf function`:

> **o,u,x,X** The unsigned int argument is converted to unsigned octal (o), unsigned decimal (u), or unsigned hexadecimal notation (x or X) in the style dddd; the letters abcdef are used for x conversion and the letters ABCDEF for X conversion. The precision specifies the minimum number of digits to appear; if the value being converted can be represented in fewer digits, it is expanded with leading zeros. The default precision is 1. The result of converting a zero value with a precision of zero is no characters.
>
> **l (ell):** Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a long int or unsigned long int argument.
>
> **ll (ell-ell):** Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a long long int or unsigned long long int argument.

Answer (score -1):

`long` versus `long long`.

In VC++ the `long` datatype is still only 32 bits.

And of course, the `printf` format `%x` is used for `int` which is 32 bits on most platforms. You want `%llx` (or possibly `%lx` if your `long` already is 64 bits).

Comment: I'm talking about C, not VC++. And I already checked size of unsigned long int which is 8 bytes.

Comment: @REALFREE Please see my updated answer. _And_ you didn't specify the compiler, just the language (and the C language allows compilers do have different bit lengths for some types)

Comment: `%u` and `%x` are mutually exclusive, `%ullx` will give the unsifgned decimal followed by the literal "llx" string. `x` is by definition unsigned. The correct format is `%llx` or `%lx`.

Comment: What about 4 bytes into 64 bits? For instance, c = "AAAA" and copy it into unsigned long int. I thought It would be 0x00000041414141 with format 0x%16lx but it shows like 0x        41414141 with empty space.

Comment: @REALFREE You want to set the field width. Please see a [`printf` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: @REALFREE, you need to pad that with zeros rather than spaces. Use `%016lx` (note the leading zero).

Answer (score -1):

%x is used to print unsigned int value & its 32 bit that's why you are getting such result.

```
%d %i     Decimal signed integer.
%o        Octal integer.
%x %X     Hex integer.
%u        Unsigned integer.
%c        Character.
%s        String.
%f        double
%e %E     double.
%g %G     double.
%p        pointer.
```

& if you want to print the remaining data try ...

```
int *p;
p=(char *)(&i)+4;

printf("integer hold: 0x%x\n", i);
printf("integer hold: 0x%x\n",*p);
```